# Using camel with Google PubSub component gives NoClassDefFoundError for com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Strings

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a SpringBoot application that uses Camel and I want to use the Google PubSub component to push messages to a topic. However when my code uses a ProducerTemplate to PubSub via:

```
producer.sendBody("google-pubsub://<my-project-id>:<my-topic-name>");
```

I get a NoClassDefFoundErr for **com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Strings**.

In my build.gradle I have:

compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-google-pubsub', version: camelVersion

compile group: 'org.apache.camel.springboot', name: 'camel-google-pubsub-starter', version: camelVersion

I have searched everywhere for a solution. I have searched through the Maven repo for any jar that might have this Strings class but no luck.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer. We are using Camel 2.24.1 currently. In org.apache.camel.component.google.pubsub.GooglePubsubEndpoint the code uses that class. In later versions of Camel apparently they don't. I tried 2.25.3 and this issue went away.

I have no idea why they used this artifact but at least I know I can get around it by using a different version of Camel.